# My regex behave differently online than in python

Tags: python, regex

So I'm currently trying to get specific parts inside a text document extracted from a pdf by textract in python.

So, this is my regex :

```
"\\n(Artikel|ARTIKEL)\s{0,}\d{0,}[EENENTWINTIG|EEN|TWEE|DRIE|VIER|VIJF|ZES|ZEVEN|ACHT|NEGEN|TIEN|ELF|TWAALF|DERTIEN|VIERTIEN|VIJFTIEN|ZESTIEN|ZEVENTIEN|ACHTTIEN|NEGENTIEN|TWINTIG|I|V|X]{0,}\s{0,}[:.!?\\-–]{0,}\s{0,}([A-Za-z\s]{0,})\\r{0,}\\n"
```

The focus is to extract the article title in a document:

Here is a online example : https://regex101.com/r/xtrra3/3/

So on this website, my regex is working perfectly, and then, when I transcribe it python with the following code, it sometimes takes the next line for no reason.

Here is the code :

```
iterator = re.finditer("\\n(Artikel|ARTIKEL)\s{0,}\d{0,}[EENENTWINTIG|EEN|TWEE|DRIE|VIER|VIJF|ZES|ZEVEN|ACHT|NEGEN|TIEN|ELF|TWAALF|DERTIEN|VIERTIEN|VIJFTIEN|ZESTIEN|ZEVENTIEN|ACHTTIEN|NEGENTIEN|TWINTIG|I|V|X]{0,}\s{0,}[:.!?\\-–]{0,}\s{0,}([A-Za-z\s]{0,})\\r\\n",txtDict["files\\0730836602.pdf"]["text"])
match = next(iterator,"Dummy text")
while(match != "Dummy text"):
    print(match.group(0))
    match = next(iterator,"Dummy text")
```

There are the results :

```
rtikel 2. zetel


Artikel 3. Voorwerp


Artikel 4. Duur


Artikel 5. Inbrengen


Artikel 6. Stortingsplicht


Artikel 8. Aard van de aandelen


Artikel 9. Overdracht van aandelen onder de levenden


Artikel 10. De overgang van aandelen wegens overlijden


Artikel 11.


Artikel 12. Waardebepaling van aandelen bij overdracht onder levenden of overgang wegens
overlijden


Artikel 14. Bestuursorgaan


Artikel 15. Bevoegdheden van het bestuursorgaan


Artikel 16. Vergoeding
Het mandaat van de bestuurder is bezoldigd en is in overeenstemming met de werkelijk uitgeoefende


Artikel 17. Controle van de vennootschap



Artikel 18. Organisatie en bijeenroeping


Artikel 19. Vergaderen van de Algemene Vergadering


Artikel 20. Bevoegdheid van de algemene vergadering


Artikel 22. Beraadslagingen


Artikel 23. Verdaging
Elke gewone of buitengewone algemene vergadering kan door het bestuursorgaan tijdens de zitting


Artikel 24. Boekjaar


Artikel 26. Ontbinding
De vennootschap kan op elk moment worden ontbonden door beslissing van de algemene


Artikel 27. Vereffenaars


Artikel 29. Kennisgeving van wijzigingen


Artikel 30. Deontologie


Artikel 31. Woonstkeuze


Artikel 32. Gerechtelijke bevoegdheid


Artikel 33. Gemeen recht
```

For no reason, it capture the next sentence for the artikel 26, 16 and 12.

It does that on other documents, but the online tool capture everything correctly.

So thanks in advance, and have a good day.

Nicolas Mahieu

Comment: You are not consistent with your backslashes. Sometimes you escape with one or two backslash. In python when writing regexes, use raw strings instead of strings: `re.finditer(r"<regex>)"` instead of `re.finditer("<regex>")` and you will be able to escape chars with only one backslash.

Comment: You are testing online on a string literal, while you need to test on a literal string. You can't expect  a regex to match two different strings the same way. You confuse a character class for a grouping, too.

Comment: The string used in the online tester is exactly the same as the one used in the dictionary.

With all the \n litteraly wrotten in it

Comment: put a little `r` before your regex string as in the website and it will work better.

Comment: @pLOPeGG Thanks for your answer, I did try it but the regex doesn't work anymore like that

Thanks for the answering

Comment: Try `r'(?m)^(Artikel|ARTIKEL)\s*\d*(?:EENENTWINTIG|EEN|TWEE|DRIE|VIER|VIJF|ZES|ZEVEN|ACHT|NEGEN|TIEN|ELF|TWAALF|DERTIEN|VIERTIEN|VIJFTIEN|ZESTIEN|ZEVENTIEN|ACHTTIEN|NEGENTIEN|TWINTIG|I|V|X)*\s*[:.!?–-]*\s*([A-Za-z\s]*)\r*\n'` - in the code, not at regex101.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for your answer.

So I did try it but the result is the same as before.
Sorry

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Btw I like your stackoverflow profile

Comment: Ok, it is due to `\s`. Try `rx = r'(?m)^(Artikel|ARTIKEL)[^\S\r\n]*\d*(?:EENENTWINTIG|EEN|TWEE|DRIE|VIER|VIJF|ZES|ZEVEN|ACHT|NEGEN|TIEN|ELF|TWAALF|DERTIEN|VIERTIEN|VIJFTIEN|ZESTIEN|ZEVENTIEN|ACHTTIEN|NEGENTIEN|TWINTIG|I|V|X)*\s*[:.!?–-]*[^\S\r\n]*([A-Za-z\t ]*)(?:\r*\n|\Z)'`. See https://ideone.com/LwlWyW

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Dude, you are so a ninja master in regex. Thank you a lot ! 
It does work ! I lost 4 hours on this problem and you solve it in 2 minutes ! Thanks a lot

Comment: Note I missed one `\s` in the suggestion in the comments,  I fixed it in my answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Nice detail explanation, thanks a lot and have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?m)^(Artikel|ARTIKEL)[^\S\r\n]*\d*(?:EENENTWINTIG|EEN|TWEE|DRIE|VIER|VIJF|ZES|ZEVEN|ACHT|NEGEN|TIEN|ELF|TWAALF|DERTIEN|VIERTIEN|VIJFTIEN|ZESTIEN|ZEVENTIEN|ACHTTIEN|NEGENTIEN|TWINTIG|I|V|X)*[^\S\r\n]*[:.!?–-]*[^\S\r\n]*([A-Za-z\t ]*)(?:\r*\n|\Z)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aUbuwn/3).

**Details**

- `(?m)` - the `re.MULTILINE` option
- `^` - start of a line
- `(Artikel|ARTIKEL)` - one of the words
- `[^\S\r\n]*` - 0+ **horizontal** whitespaces
- `\d*`- 0+ digits
- `(?:EENENTWINTIG|EEN|TWEE|DRIE|VIER|VIJF|ZES|ZEVEN|ACHT|NEGEN|TIEN|ELF|TWAALF|DERTIEN|VIERTIEN|VIJFTIEN|ZESTIEN|ZEVENTIEN|ACHTTIEN|NEGENTIEN|TWINTIG|I|V|X)*` - 0 or more repetitions of the multicharacter alternative strings
- `[^\S\r\n]*` - 0+ horizontal whitespaces
- `[:.!?–-]*`  - 0+ more `:`, `.`, `!`, etc.
- `[^\S\r\n]*` - 0+ horizontal whitespaces
- `([A-Za-z\t ]*)` - Group 2: 0+ letters or spaces or tabs
- `(?:\r*\n|\Z)`  - optional CR and LF or end of string.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/LwlWyW):

```
rx = r'(?m)^(Artikel|ARTIKEL)[^\S\r\n]*\d*(?:EENENTWINTIG|EEN|TWEE|DRIE|VIER|VIJF|ZES|ZEVEN|ACHT|NEGEN|TIEN|ELF|TWAALF|DERTIEN|VIERTIEN|VIJFTIEN|ZESTIEN|ZEVENTIEN|ACHTTIEN|NEGENTIEN|TWINTIG|I|V|X)*\s*[:.!?–-]*[^\S\r\n]*([A-Za-z\t ]*)(?:\r*\n|\Z)'
```